# Dealing with partial answers and a bounty

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, bounty

As mentioned in [Handling puzzles with multiple steps and the posting of partial answers](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/handling-puzzles-with-multiple-steps-and-the-posting-of-partial-answers/3013#3013), there are many ways to deal with giving out the accepted answer when there are multiple parts to the question.  My question is how to deal with this when there is also a bounty involved.

Some of the suggestions in that post were to post your own answer and mark it correct, which is definitely not feasible here.   Also this isn't some deeply  multi layered puzzle like the others in that post.  It essentially has 2 parts, and the first part 1 person solved, and the 2nd part another person solved.

[This is the question in question.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18344/a-single-letter-is-missing-from-each-can-you-figure-it-out-to-find-the-answer-a)

Comment: Do you think both answers are deserving of the bounty?

Comment: @BaileyM I think each deserve half

Comment: A similar question on StackOverflow meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/is-it-possible-to-divide-up-bounty-points
Does that help?